# How to take oracle 10g backup?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to take oracle 10g backup?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20788/how-to-take-oracle-10g-backup)

I followed this http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php link to create a db backup. I used this command to create db backup:

```
expdp scott/tiger@db10g full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=expdpDB10G.log
```

but I have this error message:

```
UDE-00008: operation generated ORACLE error 1033          

ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
```

please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: An export is a logical backup and should normally only be used to supplement physical backups.  See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/cncptdba.htm#CNCPT1424

Answer (score 1):

Try shutting down the database and then issuing the startup command.  Then try your script.

If you get the same error verify basic connectivity by connecting from sqlplus with the same name and password.

Check your log file location and the any operating system error logs as well.