# Resolving ORA-01033 "initialization or shutdown in progress"

Tags: oracle

I followed the instructions at http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php to create a database export.

I used:

```
expdp scott/tiger@db10g full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=expdpDB10G.log
```

to create the export. However I get this error message:

```
UDE-00008: operation generated ORACLE error 12154
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take oracle 10g backup?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20782/how-to-take-oracle-10g-backup)

Answer (score 5):

First:

```
sqlplus /nolog
```

Then:

```
connect / @bdlocal as sysdba
```

(Alternatively, use `sqlplus / as sysdba` instead of the above two steps.)

Check the status (I guess it will tell you anything but STARTUP):

```
select status from v$instance;
```

Then turn it completly off:

```
shutdown immediate;
```

Then start it:

```
startup;
```

If you get errors starting up, check the alert log and your favorite search engine (searching for the `ORA-xxxx` alert number is a good place to start). If you can't figure it out, you can ask a question about that here (including the relevant part of the alert log or any other errors you see).

Comment: thanks for quick response.
After SQL> connect / @bdlocal as sysdba executing this line

i got below error message




ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: Some possible causes for that: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-oracle-error-ora-12154-tnscould-solution/

Comment: A little bit different path for me: `$ sqlplus /nolog` / `SQL> connect system/my_password AS SYSDBA` / `SQL> shutdown immediate`; / `SQL> startup;`