# Failed to connect to oracle SQL Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I tryed to connect to SQL Plus as the admin "System", I'm sure that the password I wrote was correct but the connection failed. I also tried to connect with Scott/tiger but it failed as well.
What can be the problem, and how to resolve it please ?

this is what I get after trying to connect using both System and Scott:

[image]

Comment: Copy your attempt to connect along with the sqlplus error messages when it fails, and edit your question with the output. Impossible to answer your question without more information

Comment: I have edited my question, so that you can see the error, it seems to be the same error while attempting to connect using a wrong password doesn't it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20788/resolving-ora-01033-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress

Comment: Solutions given for other posts don't fit my problem. In fact I can not write any request on SQL Plus because I can't access through any account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded to connect after these instructions in cmd:

SQL> connect sys/manager as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> shutdown immediate;
ORA-01109: database not open

Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.
.....
ORA-01172:...
ORA-01151:....
SQL> recover database;
Media recovery complete.

SQL> alter database open;

Database altered.
SQL> exit

Answer (score 0):

Restart your database and that may clear up your issue.  Any more relevant advice will require alert logs or trace files from the database.

Comment: how could I restart the database please ?

Comment: @roukaya  from your answer you know how to shutdown and restart the database.  Did this solve your problem?

Comment: yes this resolved my problem. I just thought that there is another methode to restart database without using cmd.